# How do i make a multi-arch Docker Image to support two different platforms

Tags: docker, dockerhub

My Docker File is based on *openjdk:8-jre-alpine* which is *MultiArch* so I can use the the exact same DockerFile and build it on Intel to build an Intel Image or an Arm32 machine to build an Arm32 image.

This works fine, but the trouble is I currently have two seperate images and the customer has to use tags to make sure they pick the right one for their platform. (Also if they use a different platform such as Arm64 then I have no image for that but that is not such a problem at the moment)

But how do I provide a single multi-arch image for both with the *Supported Architectures* part, which then allow customers hardware (e.g QNAP Intel/QNAP Arm) to correctly pick the right image.

For now I only need to support two platforms so I don't mind continuing  building one image on *Arm* machine and another or *Intel* machine, I dont need to try to build all on one machine,  which I know has complications. I just want to know how to combine them so I can provide as a multi-arch single image for the user to use.

Comment: Have you tried creating a multi-arch manifest with something like: `docke manifest create your-img:latest your-img:linux-latest your-img:windows-latest`. `docker manifest` is experimental and needs to be activated. You can find examples here: https://lobradov.github.io/Building-docker-multiarch-images/ https://jugsaxony.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/20171109_JUG_Saxony_Multi-arch_Images.pdf

Comment: Please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52794668/can-i-inform-qnap-if-my-docker-image-is-intel-or-arm/52922530#52922530